# Change panel "visible" property on MasterPage from Child pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-ajax

I want to show some panel with a label, both located on a MasterPage, from inside it's child pages.. I already did the coding on the MasterPage:

```
public class MyMaster : MasterPage
{
     public void ShowPanel(string pMessage)
     {
          labelInside.Text = pMessage;
          myPanel.visible = true;
     }
}
```

Then I make the calls from child pages:

```
public void ShowPanel(string pMessage)
{
     MyMaster masterPage = this.Master as MyMaster;
     masterPage.ShowPanel(pMessage);
}
```

This "works" ok, but it won't show nothing, since I need the page to be "refreshed" in an "ajax-way" like an UpdatePanel, which I can't use because the Trigger is in another page, right?

I really need this to work.. even if you have another completely different way to do this, I would appreciate.

Comment: you could always send back some javascript to set it, or have an script run on page load that sets it from some input type=hidden value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must place your panel inside an UpdatePanel(UpdateMode conditional) and in ShowPanel call its [Update method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having the masterpage just have a placeholder for the label, but having each child page put its own content label inside that placeholder, which it would then have full control over?

Answer (score 0):

you can subClass your page, and expose a property say.. **MyPage.FooVisible**

than in your masterPage, you can:

```
myPage = this.Page as MyPage
if (myPage != null) myPage.FooVisble = false;
```

in  your page you can handle that any way you like,

```
FooVisible {
set { SomeElement.Visible = value; }
}
```

pseudo code of course :)